# Scaling pictures

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

Welcome.
I have a problem with the clarity of the image.
Images displayed by:

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/imageView"
   android:layout_width="260px"
   android:layout_height="190px"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:src="@drawable/icon" />
```

The problem is that computer shows the picture is clear but it's not on the phone.
How do I handle this?
Image has a **resolution** of **260x190** pixels.
Regards.

Comment: NEVER use absolute widths in Android development. Preferably you use width/height=fill_parent or wrap_content, if you really need pixels, use DeviceIndependentPixels: dp's.

Comment: Okay, now I'm using DP, but it changes nothing.

Comment: It doesn't have to, it was just a tip for any further Android development. I don't really understand the sentence: 'The problem is that the computer the picture is clear, and on the phone anymore. '

Comment: Sorry for my English ... The computer file is explicit and the phone is not explicit.
Now is clear?

Comment: What folder did you use to store the file? mdpi?

Comment: Are you viewing this on the actual device or the emulator?

Comment: I use drawable-hdpi folder, I viewing this on the actual device and emulator.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/imageView"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:src="@drawable/icon" />
```

That wraps the image in a way that does not strech it in any way and because the image looks bigger on bigger devices and smaller on smaller devices(aka scale).

By setting a fixed size, it shrinks on bigger devices and it blurs on smaller devices because the image gets bigger and the scale is all wrong